# Function in zsh shell with pyenv and sudo call

Tags: zsh, python

My goal is to conveniently run a python webserver module that is loaded via pyenv and virtualenv.
Depending on the port number, I might have to use sudo (port number smaller than 1025).
This is what I added to my ~/.zshrc so far:

```
uploadserver() {
  if [ $1 = 'end' ]; then
    pyenv deactivate uploadserver  
  elif [ $1 -lt 1025 ]; then 
    pyenv activate uploadserver
    sudo python -m uploadserver $1
  elif [ $1 -gt 1024 ]; then 
    pyenv activate uploadserver
    python -m uploadserver $1
  else
    print "uploadserver <port> <start/end>"    
  fi
}
```

If sudo is not required, it does what I was hoping for. However, in the sudo case it fails with "sudo: python: command not found". How can I make it work? It also fails when I run the commands manually so it does not seem to be a general scripting issue.

```
parrot@parrot ~$ uploadserver 80
sudo: python: command not found
(uploadserver) parrot@parrot ~$ uploadserver end
parrot@parrot ~$
```

Even if I add the full path to python in the virtual environment the sudo call fails:

```
(uploadserver) parrot@parrot ~$ sudo /home/parrot/.pyenv/shims/python
```

pyenv: python: command not found

**UPDATE1**
I think I found a suitable solution. If I replace the sudo call in my script with the one below it does work. I just do not know if that is a proper solution.

```
$ sudo -E env PATH=${PATH} python -m uploadserver $1
```

**UPDATE2**
After reading the proposal of Gilles 'SO- stop being evil', I decided to go for setting the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE option to my python executable. This might also not be a fitting solutions for other users but I think in my use case it is ok to handle it like this.
For me to make it work I had to run the following commands:

```
parrot@parrot ~$ sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /home/parrot/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/bin/python3.12
```

The python in pyenv is just a wrapper and setting the capability to this file does not work:

```
(uploadserver) parrot@parrot ~$ which python                                                                                                                
/home/parrot/.pyenv/shims/python
(uploadserver) parrot@parrot ~$ getcap /home/parrot/.pyenv/shims/python                                                                                     
/home/parrot/.pyenv/shims/python cap_net_bind_service=ep
(uploadserver) parrot@parrot ~$ python -m uploadserver 80
...
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Sudo removes most environment variables (or resets them to a “safe” default for a few like `PATH`). This is necessary when a sudo rule gives access to a specific command, because the command might work in an unexpected way in the presence of certain environment variables and thus allow the caller to do more than desired. For example, `LD_PRELOAD` would allow the caller to run arbitrary code with elevated privileges. So would `PYTHONPATH` if the command is a Python program.

This security feature is not necessary in the specific case where a sudo rule allows arbitrary command as the target user. But sudo doesn't relax the feature by default, both because it would be harder to do and because it would make it easier for the administrator to make mistakes.

If allowed by the sudo rules, you can tell it to preserve almost all environment variables with `--preserve-env` (`-E`), or you can set specific variables (`sudo FOO=bar mycommand` is functionally equivalent to `sudo env FOO=bar mycommand`). So you can run `sudo PATH="$PATH" python …`.

However, this is a bad idea because it starts your program as root. You're relying on your Python script to correctly drop privileges after opening the privileged port. You're also relying on it not to do anything unexpected before dropping privileges, for example while parsing the command line and any configuration file.

Instead of sudo, use a tool that's specialized in (1) opening a port and (2) dropping privileges before (3) executing a server program. This can be [`tcpd`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcpd&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+14.0-RELEASE+and+Ports), [the systemd equivalent](https://serverfault.com/questions/916807/net-bind-capability-with-systemd), [authbind](https://packages.debian.org/stable/authbind), or one of many other possibilities [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux) [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/1079881/give-non-root-users-permission-to-use-one-port).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue with my approach! As I only use it in a VM for testing purposes, most solutions seem a little overkill and some do also not offer the flexibility I need. The CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE option might have been a good compromise between convenience and security but unfortunately, I could not get it to work.

Comment: I updated my post to include the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE option which I eventually could get to work.